# Secure cross-platform instant messaging software

Tags: cross-platform, security, chat, encryption

What is secure - as in confidentiality of message contents - instant messaging software with at least following features:

- No need to setup (and maintain) my own server
- Support for Windows, OS X and Linux
- End-to-end encryption to prevent listening message on the server
- One-to-one and group chats

Answer (score 8):

You may use *any* [XMPP client](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) that supports [OpenPGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#OpenPGP) or [OTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging). So each person could use a client of their choice, no need for all to use the same.

But if the *same* client should be used cross-platform, have a look at [**Jitsi**](https://jitsi.org/) (License: LGPL), which uses Java. It supports OTR. See this (old) video: [Your first OTR text chat with Jitsi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgx7VSrDGjk).

(XMPP works, like email, not with a specific provider only. So you can make your choice which provider to use, and again, each person could use a different one. For example [@jabber.org](http://www.jabber.org/), [@dukgo.com](https://duck.co/blog/xmpp-services-at-duckduckgo), [@gmx.com](http://www.gmx.com/), …)

Comment: I think it's okay to use different software on different platforms, as long as those are compatible. But Jitsi seems to fit rather well.

Comment: Related question: [Which XMPP clients support OpenPGP (XEP-0027)?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/235/60)

Comment: +1 XMPP and OTR should cover the need really well, I do use them myself everyday.

Comment: I'm throwing in http://www.pidgin.im . Available for all OS and prepackaged for most Distributions.

Comment: OTR is great for one-on-one conversations, but it doesn't support group chat, which was one of the requirements set forward by the OP. There has been considerable talk about a *multi-party OTR* (mpOTR for short) in the past years, but as far as I know so far they didn't pan out, yet.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [Tox](https://tox.chat/), a new encrypted IM client. It's in alpha stage, but the chat feature seems to work quite well.

It has all the features you want:

- One on one messaging and group chats.
- It encrypts messages.
- Supports Mac OSX, Windows, and Linux.
- No setup needed.

[image: Venom UI]

As mentioned earlier, the software is still in an alpha state, but I think it shows a lot of promise.

Comment: Is it still in alpha state?

Comment: No, it is no longer in alpha state.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Cryptocat](https://crypto.cat/), a browser extension for encrypted chatting (similar to IRC, but more secure ;)

Cryptocat supports all major browsers including:

- Chrom(e)(ium)
- Firefox
- Safari
- Opera
- OSX via the Apple App store.

[image: Cryptocat UI]

Comment: One of the requirements is “no need to setup (and maintain) my own server”. Are there public Cryptocat servers?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, there are public Cryptocat servers… accessible via their browser extensions and apps. [Here's their network monitor](https://crypto.cat/monitor/) (third-party cryptocat networks not included). Btw.: [Cryptocat's network is located at *"Bahnhof"*](https://blog.crypto.cat/2013/02/cryptocat-network-now-in-swedish-nuclear-bunker/) (Swedish webhost, known for having hosted *WikiLeaks* and *The Pirate Bay*).

Comment: Quick update: Cryptocat has been unavailable since February 2015, due to it's author's lack of time. In his message on [crypto.cat](https://crypto.cat/) he mentions a full rewrite of the Cryptocat software, but it is unclear if/when this will be available.