# Puzzle-adventure PC games (like Safecracker)

Tags: windows, game

I am looking for alternative games like [Safecracker: The Ultimate Puzzle Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safecracker:_The_Ultimate_Puzzle_Adventure). It is a game full of riddles and you try to solve them through a story.

Here is a [gameplay video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDKwajEfZkM).

More info:

- Platform: Windows
- Age: I don't care about its age. Even if it is a really old game or new with highend graphics
- The aim of the game should be solving the riddles and not a game with only a few of them as a side-story

Comment: Would investigation games qualify for your third point? "solving the riddles" is not exactly their final goal, but they make you go through lots of puzzles to find answers

Comment: I am not 100% sure about it, but the third bullet means that I don't want any other action on the game like fighting or shooting. There are several adventure games with riddles but they also have fighting scenes between the characters.

Comment: The ones I have in mind don't have fight scenes, but they sometimes do have long dialogs between characters

Comment: That's not a problem. You can post all of them as an answer

Comment: You might also want to check the answers on: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/767/6834

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions which I'll post as a single answer since they are similiar

1. [Art of Murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_of_Murder_(series)): A series consisting of 3 games released in 2008, 2009, and 2010. They are point-and-click adventure games involving murder investigations. The player has to collect evidence usually by solving puzzles and interrogating people. There are also instances of "McGyvering" where the player has to use items in their surroundings to escape a situation. They start off fairly simple, then get progressively more difficult.

[image]

2. [Martin Mystère: Operation Dorian Gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Myst%C3%A8re:_Operation_Dorian_Gray): Another investigation game. The puzzles are much more challenging than in Art of Murder, but it's the same principle: Gathering evidence, interrogating people, and getting into and out of trouble in the process.

[image]

3. [The Nancy Drew series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nancy_Drew#Video_games): Same principle, but the stories are more family-friendly (usually involve thefts and forgeries rather than murders). That puzzles are still interesting and somewhat challenging

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know safecracker and it always struck me as a light version of the Myst adventures.

So try Myst (it's an old game but the mother of those kind of games), realMyst (a remake).

[image: MystCover]

Something also similar is "The Room" or "The Room Two".

[image: RoomCover]