# Free/libre XMPP client for Firefox OS

Tags: open-source, xmpp, firefox-os

I need an XMPP client for Firefox OS (1.3).

I want it for text chatting only, so audio/video chat or file transfers are not required.

It **must** be …

- 100% **FLOSS**
- actively **maintained**
- a **native** app (no Web service)

It **should** …

- support **multiple accounts**
- offer some kind of **end-to-end encryption** (e.g., [OpenPGP](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/235/60) and/or OTR)
- support **MUCs**

Answer (score 1):

[**Loqui IM**](http://loqui.im/) ([included in Firefox Marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/loqui)) is a chat client supporting XMPP.

[image: Loqui IM interface showing an XMPP chat between two users]

It’s FLOSS, licensed under [GNU AGPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html).

You’ll notice that it’s an alpha version. Currently, there are some bugs with the XMPP implementation, but it seems to be actively developed. I can’t recommend it as a stable solution at the moment, but I’m sure it will improve over the next time.

A possible showstopper for many: **Loqui IM’s roster doesn’t show who is online!** You have to open a chat with a contact to see if they are online. It [seems to be intentional](https://github.com/loqui/im/issues/381) that way.

[Issues](https://github.com/loqui/im/issues) can be reported on GitHub. (There is also a [mailing list](http://lists.waalt.com/pipermail/loqui.core/) for developers, but it seems to be in Spanish only.)

About the optional features:

- **multiple accounts**: yes, supported
  [image: Loqui IM interface showing multiple XMPP accounts]
- **end-to-end encryption**: yes, it [supports](https://github.com/loqui/im/issues/43) OTR
- **MUCs**: yes, supported

Comment: There is also an online demo: https://demo.loqui.im/